# How to make responsive Toolbar in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a toolbar as the code follows:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="main">
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="action/">Do something</a>
    <form class="col-md-3 input-group pull-right" method="GET"> 
        <input type="text" name="search" id="id_search" class="form-control" maxlength="200">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-group" name="submit_search" value="Search">Search</button>
    </span>
    </form>
</div></div></div>
```

You can check the demo on this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Se98n/1/

In smaller screen resolutions the toolbar breaks in two lines and it could fit in just one.

How can I make it more responsive?

I think it should stay in one line until it is impossible, then, the search and the button get left aligned with some space between then to keep the page aesthetics. But other behaviors are still acceptable if the layout don't stay weird.

Comment: `<form class="col-md-3 col-sm-9 col-xs-8 input-group pull-right" method="GET">` Do something like this, use `sm` and `xs` for smaller sizes.

Answer (score 2):

see: http://bootply.com/82277

**css**:

```
@media (max-width: 480px)
{
    .pull-right{float:none !important;}

    .btn-group > .btn:first-child {
     margin-left: 5px;

       }

    .btn-toolbar > .btn-group:first-child {margin-bottom:15px;}
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
<div id="main">
<div class="btn-toolbar">
<div class="btn-group"> 
<a class="btn btn-default" href="action/">Do something</a>  
</div>
<div class="btn-group pull-right"> 
    <form class="input-group" method="GET"> 

        <input type="text" name="search" id="id_search" class="form-control" maxlength="200">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-group" name="submit_search" value="Search">Search</button>
    </span>
    </form>
</div>     
</div>
</div>
</div>
```